# Discord.py cant Ban Fetched User

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I was trying to ban someone by the UserID but somehow I cant ban Users by fetching them with their ID. Is this an Error or what?

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, userid):
    member = await client.fetch_user(userid)
    await member.ban()
    await ctx.send("Banned")
```

Error:

```
Ignoring exception in command ban:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maddo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\maddo\Desktop\Batbot\main.py", line 58, in ban
    await member.ban()
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'ban'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maddo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\maddo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\maddo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'ban'
```

Comment: Why would you want to fetch the ID? Is the user not on the server anymore?

Comment: No, the User is on the Server, I simply want to add ID Ban Support to my Bot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [discord.Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20member#discord.Member.ban) as a required argument to ban users from your server either by ID or mention.

You should **never** use `fetch` for this, because then you would make a request to the API, this can cause a rate limit after some time.

**A simple ban command could be:**

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member): # ID/mention needed
    await ctx.guild.ban(member) # Get your guild and ban the member
    await ctx.send(f"{member} got banned") # Send a message
```